# How do I use block_view_alter for the template file?

Tags: 8, blocks

I want to alter a view block. I used [`hook_block_view_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/8.2.x), but this is not working in a template theme Drupal 8.

How do I use `hook_block_view_alter()` in template theme?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! The only part clear in the question is that you are trying to use `hook_block_view_alter()`. Since you are talking of code you wrote, you should show what code you wrote. _It is not working_ is not much helpful. What did you get from the code you are using, and what is the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

I think from the *.theme file you should use [`hook_preprocess_HOOK`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x)

Comment: Yes, Drupal doesn't invoke `hook_block_view_alter()` for themes.

Comment: Used hook_preprocess_block which Could not call region of each block for check by handle code !

Comment: @HenryTran Your comment is not clear at all. First, you need to show the code you are using, and tell us exactly what you are trying to achieve; then, we can answer your question. Until then, the only possible answer is this. Drupal doesn't invoke `hook_block_view_alter()` when implemented from a theme.